# Eclipse Syntax error android:targetSdkVersion="10"

Tags: eclipse

Hi I am required to add a target SDK version for libGdx, but eclipse if throwing an "errror" - No resource identifier found for attribute targetSdkVersion in package android-

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

this is confusing the heck out of me as it won't allow my App to work on a device.

any help really appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have version 10 SDK downloaded (2.3.3)?